# Edit Grease Pencil Strength

Tags: grease-pencil

i've just started studying Grease Pencil and did some basic animations. After some work i've noticed that all my strokes were painted with a semi transparent strength.

[image: screen]

[image: detail]

**Can i change the strength of my strokes after i've drawed them?** i'm sure is not a matter of material opacity.

**edit**: i've obtained what i'm looking for using the modifier Noise for grease pencil , but i'd like to **make it permanent**, moreover, when i click apply Blender Crashes

[image: noise modifier on strength]

thank you.

Comment: Have You found solution for changing strength after drawing? Please let me know if yes. I have same problem right now.

Comment: @Bernard Does any of the answers help you ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go to the Sculpt mode, and use the Strength brush.

Comment: Thank you very much sir ;)

Comment: Yes! This was driving me nuts and would never ever have thought of going into sculpt mode, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can add an *Opacity* modifier to the Grease Pencil object.

Set the type to *Uniform* and keep the *Strength* to $1$ to get full opacity.

If *Uniform* is unchecked, the factor will act as an addition to the stroke, but it acts in an unintuitive way.

Between $0$ and $1$, the factor will decrease the opacity by a set amount. (eg with a factor of $0.6$, the opacity will decrease by $1 - 0.6 = 0.4$).

Similarly, between $1$ and $2$, the opacity will increase by a set amount. (eg with a factor of $1.4$, the opacity will increase by $1.4 - 1 = 0.4$).

Note that you can also apply the modifier to a fill, but it will only decrease the opacity, never increase it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is now a shortcut to do that: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
It works in Edit Mode and changes the opacity of the selected strokes (so you can just press <kbd>A</kbd> before to select all of them)
It works with version 2.93 (but maybe already with 2.92?)

Comment: This is so much better because sculpt can be really slow when their are many strokes.