# How to edit the transparency of the grease pencil stroke?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]
In my viewport, there is a stroke drawn lightly by the tablet pressure.
However, the transparency of the material assigned to the stroke is 1, so it is a fairly dark color.
Since the cause of this problem is the pressure applied to the stroke, not the set value of the material, I want to adjust the transparency by editing the properties of the stroke.
**Q: How to access the transparency properties of already drawn strokes without touching the material?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit Grease Pencil Strength](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140264/edit-grease-pencil-strength)

Comment: @wilks Thank you. It works for me.
However, it would be nice if the intensity of the stroke could be adjusted in edit mode, as you can use both sculpting and edit modes for mash editing. When adjusting in edit mode, the intensity of all stroke points can be controlled numerically and accurately.

Comment: yep, I even think it should be an option in draw mode cos having to go in sculpt mode doesn't feel logical.