# Grease pencil appears translucent

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

I am just learning about Grease Pencil, and mine always appears see-through, both in the viewport and when rendered.  I do not know how to fix this.  Here are screenshots of the viewport and render respectively:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default Strenght for the grease pencil is 0.600.

[image]

To draw dark strokes set it to 1

Additionally you can use an opacity modifier to make existing strokes darker.

Read:
[Edit Grease Pencil Strength](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140264/edit-grease-pencil-strength)?